# Using xml::simple - unable to get specific format output

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, xml-simple, data-dumper

Input file :SN.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<root>
<category cname='Cname1' id='c1'>
  <subcat key='3' sname='Subname1' sid='sid1'>
    <prod key='1' pname='Productname'>value1</prod>
  </subcat>
</category>
</root>
```

I am using these code for converting XML file to hash.

```
my $config = XML::Simple->new();
$config = XMLin('SN.xml');
print Dumper($config);
```

I'm getting below output :

```
'3' => {
          'sid' => 'sid1',
              'sname' => 'Subname1',
                   'prod' => {
                               'content' => 'value1',
                               'pname' => 'Productname',
                               'key' => '1'
                                                   }
        },
```

I am expecting to get output below, please help me to get this..

```
  '3' => {
             'sid' => 'sid1',
                     'sname' => 'Subname1',
                                       'prod' => {
                                                 '1' => {
                                                        'pname' => 'Productname',
                                                        'content' =>'value1'
                                                      },
                                                 }
             },
```

Please suggest me any other module producing this result too..

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Your XML is not valid! Maybe it's a typo? Line #4 you close a tag `</subcat>` that was never opened.

Comment: Thanks psxls! This not a error,i corrected it. I want ouput which i mentioned above format.

Comment: The line `my $config = XML::Simple->new();` is useless here. You don't use the created `XML::Simple` object at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $xs = XML::Simple->new( ForceArray => 1 );
my $config = $xs->XMLin('SN.xml');
print Dumper $config;
```

The `ForceArray` option will force nested elements to be put in arrayrefs even if there is only one nested element. This allows the default `KeyAttr` option to kick in and recognise your 'key' attributes.